# Loading p5js of react-p5 npm package to NextJS app shows "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, p5.js

This is my Code Which I got from [react-p5 typescript Example](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5#typescript) and modified it a bit

```
import Sketch from "react-p5";
import p5Types from "p5";

type InputParameterType = {};

function P5JsComponent({}: InputParameterType) {
  let x = 50;
  const y = 50;

  //See annotations in JS for more information
  const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
    p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(canvasParentRef);
  };

  const draw = (p5: p5Types) => {
    p5.background(0);
    p5.ellipse(x, y, 70, 70);
    x++;
  };
  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
}

export default P5JsComponent;
```

My Parent Component in My NextJs App is 'homepage.tsx' which is present in the pages directory.

```
import Head from "next/head";
import P5JsComponent from "@/components/P5JsComponent";

function homepage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
       <P5JsComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default homepage;
```

I am getting a `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error when I run this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server-side-rendering, we haven't global variables from the browser, like the "window" variable.
P5JsComponent must be rendered on the client-side.

Import P5JsComponent with no SSR:

```
const P5JsComponent = dynamic(
  () => import("@/components/P5JsComponent"),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import